# Is nsis !system call broken (when calling xcopy)?

Tags: nsis

I am working with the latest 3.0b2 release and noticed that calling xcopy via !system call does not work.

I have a xcopy call which works flawlessly when called manually via command line but silently fails when piping it through !system.

(Note: I need `!system` as this is a compile time operation that must succeed before I can package data)

Here is a sample nsi script

```
!system 'xcopy'
!error "just exit"
```

Calling `xcopy` should return some output about invalid argument count etc, but xcopy is entirely silent. If I replace it with `robocopy` I get some output.

The really odd thing: I fired up Process Monitor and watched on Process Start of a valid xcopy call, it was something like that:

```
xcopy "d:\tool\*.pdb" "d:\dest\"  /y /g /k /r /s /f
```

It copied everything. But then I ran the exact same line in nsis with `!system` and ProcMon displayed **exactly** the same Process start call. I diffed both parameter sets, same working directory, same command line but the call via `!system` did not proceed to copy files. Procmon even says that the second call had an exit code of 0.

It's everything cool except it does not copy files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567912/why-would-c-sharp-processstartinforedirectstandardoutput-cause-xcopy-process-to) to be a [bug](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ab3c0cc7-83c2-4a86-9188-40588b7d1a52/processstart-of-xcopy-only-works-under-the-debugger?forum=netfxbcl) in XCopy, it fails to do anything if there is no valid StdIn handle. This bug seems to exist in several Microsoft tools that use the undocumented ulib.dll library to handle its input/output.

[This Wine commit](https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-patches/2014-February/130787.html) claims that <= Win2003 requires a console handle but a anonymous pipe worked for me on WinXP.

The next NSIS version will provide a empty StdIn pipe to the child to work around this bug, in the meantime you can use:

```
!system 'xcopy < nul'
```

or

```
!system 'start /wait /min xcopy'
```

Comment: This works indeed if I call xcopy in nsis and for my scenario where I call powershell which in turn calls xcopy, but passing null to powershell did the trick. How did you correlate that with NSIS? I did quite an amount of before.

Comment: @Samuel: I knew that !system changed in NSISv3 because I rewrote it when it gained Unicode support. The old version just used the system() c library function, the new version is pure Win32 with pipes. I first thought it was a codepage conversion problem but after ruling that out I investigated the pipes and tried adding a stdin pipe as part of that...

Comment: your answer indicates that it is ok, that I wasn't able to infer the solution from googling around :)